# Use grep to report back only line numbers

Tags: grep

I have a file that possibly contains bad formatting (in this case, the occurrence of the pattern `\\backslash`). I would like to use `grep` to return only the line numbers where this occurs (as in, the match was here, go to line # x and fix it).

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to print the line number (`grep -n`) and not the match or line itself.

I can use another regex to extract the line numbers, but I want to make sure grep cannot do it by itself. `grep -no` comes closest, I think, but still displays the match.

Comment: The most useful answer for me was in the question: `grep -no`! This did what I came here to try and do! (i.e. not print the line which is sometimes very long in, e.g., minified javascript source files.)

Answer (score 209, accepted):

try:

```
grep -n "text to find" file.ext | cut -f1 -d:
```

Comment: On my machine, this is only printing the matched files without line numbers (so if I have 3 matches inside a file it is only printed once) which is very useful still...

Comment: @MarioAwad, you should manipulate `-f` param. For me it was `-f2`. (Know this is old stuff, but I think it could help some poor souls)

Comment: thanks for lovely old unix adhoc shell scripting. this shows that flexible tools are worth their complexity and learning curve!

Comment: `grep -n "text to find" file.ext | cut -f1,2 -d:` shows the file name and the line number.

Comment: @jondim it only shows the filename if there is more than one file being searched; you need to add `-H` to force it to show the filename when there is only one file. Conversely, you can always use `-h` to tell it not to output the filename no matter how many files you're grepping.

Answer (score 55):

If you're open to using AWK:

```
awk '/textstring/ {print FNR}' textfile
```

In this case, FNR is the line number. AWK is a great tool when you're looking at grep|cut, or any time you're looking to take grep output and manipulate it.

Comment: Uses one process (which mattered more in the past, but still), and easy enough to understand for awk beginners!

Comment: `NR` works as well when there's only one file being examined, as in this case.

Comment: Simply Brilliant! It is so fast!

Answer (score 52):

All of these answers require grep to generate the entire matching lines, then pipe it to another program. If your lines are very long, it might be more efficient to use just sed to output the line numbers:

```
sed -n '/pattern/=' filename
```

Comment: Brilliant use of `sed`!

Comment: My favourite answer.

Answer (score 2):

Bash version

```
    lineno=$(grep -n "pattern" filename)
    lineno=${lineno%%:*}
```

Comment: And what happens if more than one line matches that pattern?

Comment: @izabera add | tail -1

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the answers with `sed` and `awk` for just getting the line number, rather than using `grep` to get the entire matching line and then removing that from the output with `cut` or another tool. For completeness, you can also use Perl:

```
perl -nE 'say $. if /pattern/' filename
```

or Ruby:

```
ruby -ne 'puts $. if /pattern/' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

using only **grep**:

`grep -n "text to find" file.ext | grep -Po '^[^:]+'`

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want the second field after the colon, not the first.

`grep -n "text to find" file.txt | cut -f2 -d:`

Comment: This works if you want to matching text, but in the case the line number is what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of lines matched the pattern:

```
grep -n "Pattern" in_file.ext | wc -l
```

To extract matched pattern

```
sed -n '/pattern/p' file.est
```

To display line numbers on which pattern was matched

```
grep -n "pattern" file.ext | cut -f1 -d:
```

Comment: 1st should just be "grep -c 'Pattern' in_file.ext". 2nd should be "grep -o 'Pattern' in_file.ext". No need to involve sed or wc.

Answer (score 0):

bash:

```
readarray a <<< $(grep -n Pattern File)
echo ${a[@]%%:*}
for l in ${a[@]%%:*}
```

ksh93/bash(watchout lastpipe)

```
grep -n Pattern File | while IFS=: read l z
do echo $l
done
```