# How can I use grep to get the line number without the output?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use grep to report back only line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958841/use-grep-to-report-back-only-line-numbers)

I only want to see the line number.  I don't need to see the remaining output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958841/use-grep-to-report-back-only-line-numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipe your `grep -n` output, which normally looks something like:

```
11: stuff that matched
43: more stuff that matched
```

through sed to strip out the matching parts:

```
grep -n pattern file | sed -e 's/:.*//g'

11
43
```

Comment: Wonderful,thank you,though I have anther question:how can i get the first match result?

Comment: And can you introduce the string " :.* ",what are they representative?

Comment: its a substitution of the colon and anything that appears after it with the empty string "//" there is an explanation of the regular expression here where you can also play around with it: http://regex101.com/r/nS9jM7

Comment: Ok,but you don't anwser me the anther question:how can i get the first match result?

Comment: If you want to get the first line (of anything) you can pipe it to "head -n1" so "grep -n pattern file | sed -e 's/:.*//g' | head -n1

Answer (score 0):

`grep -n` or `--line-number` option will do this for you. You can find this information in the grep help file, which you can find by using `grep --help` or `grep --help | less` to read it more carefully. Also consider using the manual page: `man grep`

Comment: grep -h is for suppress the prefixing filename on output,but I don't want the content , not the filename.

Comment: Sorry, you're totally right.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` too.

```
grep -n word file | awk -F: '{ print $1 }'
```

As @Barmar pointed out you could just use an `awk` one-liner as such:

```
awk '/regex/ { print NR }' file
```

Since you don't have `awk` you could also use `cut`:

```
grep -n word file | cut -d: -f1
```

Comment: for fun, just a grep pipeline too: grep -n alert test.html | egrep -o '^[0-9]+:' | egrep -o '^[0-9]+'    #:-)

Comment: If you're going to use `awk`, why bother with `grep`, since `awk` can do regex matching itself and it has a variable with the line number?

Comment: @Barmar There is always more than one way to do something. I just quickly wrote that up.

Comment: Unfortunatly,my linux is not have awk..

Comment: @choujayyl What Linux do you have that does not have awk?

Comment: @squiguy awk: cannot open /home/user/myexe/external_symbols.awk (No such file or directory)...

Comment: @choujayyl Try using `/usr/bin/awk` or `/bin/awk`.

Comment: @squiguy how can i change the path ..

Comment: @choujayyl You can make an alias in your shell.  That is really odd though that awk is not already in that path.