# How to get column index of field in unix shell

Tags: shell, csv, unix, sed

I have a csv file with headers:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
```

I would like to do something

```
cat abc.csv | sed "something to split them" | grep "e"  

#position of "e"
```

Can someone guide me how do I get the column idx of which header 'e' is at?

Comment: So given `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h` you want it to tell you that the `e` is in the 5th column?

Comment: @MarkReed Yes this is what i needed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to say "which column is this value in", you have a number of options, but this works:

```
sed -n $'1s/,/\\\n/gp' abc.csv | grep -nx 'e'
#output: 5:e
```

If you want to get just the number out of that:

```
sed -n $'1s/,/\\\n/gp' abc.csv | grep -nx 'e' | cut -d: -f1
#output: 5
```

Explanation:

Since the headers are on the first line of the file, we use the `-n` option to tell `sed` not to print out all the lines by default. We then give it an expression that starts with `1`, meaning it is only executed on the first line, and ends with `p`, meaning that line gets printed out afterward.

The expression uses ANSI quotes (`$'`...`'`) simply so it's easier to read: you can put a newline in it with `\n` instead of having to include a literal newline. Regardless, by the time the shell is done with it, the expression `$'1s/,/\\\n/gp'` gets passed to sed as `1s/,/\
/gp`, which tells it to replace every comma on the first line with a newline and then print out the result. The output of just the sed on your example would be this:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

(If your CSV file has many lines, you may want to add `;q` to the end of the `sed` command so that it quits after that first line instead of continuing to read and do nothing with the rest of the lines.)

We then pipe that output through a `grep` command looking for `e`. We pass the `-x` option so that it only matches lines consisting of exactly 'e', not just any line containing an 'e' (Thanks @Marcel and @Sundeep), plus the `-n` option that tells it to include the line number of matching lines in its output. In the example, it outputs `5:e`, where the `5:` says that the rest of the output is from the 5th line of the input.

We can then pipe that through `cut` with a field delimiter (`-d`) of `:` to extract just the first field (`-f1`), which is the line number in the sed output - which is the field number in the original file.

Comment: @aceminer, you need to use grep -n "^yourtext$" or you will have problems with substrings. "^" indicates the start of the line and "$" the end of the line. You can check my answer for more details.

Comment: or use `-x` option

Comment: I didn't know -x @Sundeep. It's so beautifu!!! I have incorporated to my answer also. Thanks!

Comment: there is also `-w` option to match whole words.. avoids needing `\b` in most cases... :)

Comment: another suggestion, (found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958841/use-grep-to-report-back-only-line-numbers) - use `sed -n '/^e$/='` to get only line number.. avoids grep + cut

Comment: assumes the data looks like the example - no regexp metacharacters in the target field name and relies on non-POSIX sed and bash-only shell constructs, not a general solution.

Comment: Point taken, @EdMorton. It still makes more of an attempt to meet the OP's stated intent instead of only working on their supplied sample data.

Answer (score 8):

1. **head** is selecting the first line (header);
2. **tr** is replacing the delimiter for line breaks;
3. **grep** is selecting the line that contains exactly the string you want (substrings are ignored) and the line number is shown as well. In the example, we will have **5:e**;
4. **cut** is using '**:**' as delimiter and selecting the first column. So just the line number will be shown.

```
head -n1 abc.csv | tr "," "\n" | grep -nx e |  cut -d":" -f1
```

File content:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
```

String that you want:

```
e
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Yeah, Mark. You are right. I have updated the answer with "head -1". Thank you very much. And +1 for your  good  answer.

Comment: suggest to use `code` (the `{}` icon) to format instead of quote.. it will give syntax highlighting :)

Comment: Good point, @Sundeep. Actually, I tried but { }  is not working for me now. Just this time o_O

Comment: looks like it doesn't detect code formatting immediately following bullets or numbering... I added a dummy `<b>` tag as workaround :D

Comment: nb: POSIXly correct `head` takes `-n 1` instead of just `-1`

Comment: But the documentation says to use this manner: -n, --lines=[-]NUM
I didn't get your point about POSIX, @MarkReed

Comment: @MarcelJacquesMachado - the POSIX spec says that head takes the argument `-n count`, even though the traditional implementation took (and most still do) just `-`*count*. Some implementations (including, I believe, GNU coreutils, if a certain environment variable is set) strictly enforce the POSIX requirement and die with a usage error when passed `-`*num*.

Comment: OK,@MarkReed. Good point. I have updated the answer. Thanks for sharing your knowledge =)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of hack, but it will give you the index of `e`:

```
head -n1 abc.csv | grep -oE '^.*(,|^)e(,|$)' | tr -Cd , | wc -c
```

It works by extracting the part of the top row up to the `e`, then it removes all characters except for the commas, and finally it counts the number of commas.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat ip.txt 
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

With `perl`

```
$ # can also use: perl -F, -lane 'print grep {$F[$_-1] eq "e"} 1..$#F+1; exit'
$ perl -F, -lane 'foreach (0..$#F){ print $_+1 if $F[$_] eq "e" } exit' ip.txt 
5
```

With `awk`

```
$ awk -F, '{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i=="e"){print i} exit}' ip.txt 
5
```

In both cases:

- Input line is split on `,` and comparison made against each element to find matching index
- No output if a match is not found
- `exit` is used to quit immediately after reading first line

Answer (score 1):

Following command will loop through all the fields and check for the string "e". If Found then print the index of that location.

For **all** the lines:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="e") print i}' input.csv
```

IF it's limited to **header**/ first row then :

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="e") {print i;exit}}' input.csv
```

Example:

```
echo "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h" |awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="e") {print i}'
5
```

Comment: Real file might have many lines; should probably put an `(NR==1)` guard on that expression and turn the `print i` into `{ print i; exit }`.

Comment: @MarkReed : hey mark, but that would make solution limited to first row only. Why would we would limit it ?

Comment: OP is looking for "which column number is this header".  Headers are the first row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{print (index($0,"e")+1)/2}' file
5
```

Comment: assumes the data looks like the example - one character per field, only one line.  not a general solution.

Comment: Absolutely correct, it addresses the OPs question as all of our solutions do. Yours, for example, would fail if the target field name contained RE metacharacters. So why the downvote?